# Creating a view in IOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: uiview, swift3, uiimageview, uitextview, ios10

Hi I want to create a view which looks something like below -

[image: Text View]

What I tried so far is I put two properties called image and text inside an `UIView` and tried to initialise the image view and text field and added in `UIView` I am able to see the image but not the text. May be I am missing proper constraints to put or something else. Can please someone help on what should be the best approach for this.

I would prefer it to be done without much involvement of storyboard i.e setting constraints for different views using storyboard. I am fine setting constraints in code. As you see it is a fairly reusable element and hence I want it as an class which can be assigned to any uiview and that should be it. Please correct me if something can be done better?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions: the entire picture provided above is contained in a UIView and we are using Storyboard.

Refer to this picture for clarity in the explanation.

[image]

1. Make sure the outermost View has enough constraits so AutoLayout can properly size the view. If this doesn't happen, nothing past this point will matter.
2. Create 2 Views. Each has the same width as the container and is half the height. Place one in the upper half and one in the lower half. These are the ones with the blue and orange backgrounds.
3. Add an ImageView to the top View (blue background). Make the ImageView half the height of its Superview. Make the ImageView centered vertically in container. Add a constraint for the leading edge of the ImageView to be the same as the leading edge of the Superview margin. Add an AspectRatio constraint to the ImageView of 1:1.

[image]

4. Add a TextField to the top View (blue background). Center the TextField vertically in the container. Add a constraint for the HorizontalSpace between TextField leading and ImageView trailing and make the constant 8. Add a constraint for the TrailingSpace to the TextView for the SuperView trailing margin.

[image]

5. Change the Placeholder Text for the TextField to "Email"
6. Place the image in the imageview.
7. Repeat for the orange background View.

For the bottom borders, use this:

```
    extension UIView{
        func addBottomBorder(borderThickness: CGFloat, color: UIColor , widthPct: CGFloat) {
                let border = UIView()

                border.backgroundColor = color
                border.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin]

                var x: CGFloat = 0
                let width = self.frame.size.width * widthPct

                if widthPct < 1{
                    x = (self.frame.size.width - width) / 2
                }

                border.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: self.frame.size.height - borderThickness, width: width, height: borderThickness);
                self.addSubview(border)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is perfect, however I will prefer it to be done without much involvement of storyboard i.e setting constraints for different views using storyboard. I am fine setting constraints in code. As you see it is a fairly reusable element and hence I want it as an class which can be assigned to any uiview and that should be it. Please correct me if something can be done better?